# How do I avoid code duplication for fragments?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-tabbed-activity

If I want to create a tabbed activity with more than 10 swipable fragments, what other option do I have rather than to create 10 different Fragment classes with layouts and inflate they based on their position in the tabbed layout.

That obviously sounds like a lot of duplicated code.

My question, fair and simple, is there any other way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create one fragment class and then use the `int` value based on its position in the tabs to determine which layout to inflate in the `onCreate` method where you usually inflate a single layout view.

Example

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if(tabNumber == 1){
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_layout1);
    }else if(tabNumber == 2){
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_layout2);
    }else{
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_layout3);
    }

}
```

Comment: That makes sense, I'll try that!

Comment: Don't forget that fragment could be recreated by `FragmentManager` so `tabNumber` should be passed through `Bundle` and retrieved in `onCreate()`.

Comment: I think I got a hold of it now. Thanks